# How to save or merge two arrays into one array before Submit in Twig?

Tags: html, twig

I have a modal form in Twig to add a new questions to a ticket system.
In this form I can add more options(answers) to the question and they will be in array.

And I have radio button near every answer filled, I want this button values to be in the same array for the answers.
I'm new to twig so I tried to use set but I didn't knew how exactly it should be.

Here is my code :

```
<div class="form-inline" id="showOptions" name"test">
   <input class="form-control" name="answers[]" type="text" placeholder="Answer here"/>
   <button onclick="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span>
   </button>
   <div class="radio">
      <fieldset id="group1">
         <label>bla bla?</label>&nbsp;
         <label class="radio" ><input name="decision[]" type="radio" value"1">Ja</label>
         <label class="radio" ><input name="decision[]" type="radio" value"0">Nein</label>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

and it would looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

create the field name like this.

```html
<div class="form-inline" id="showOptions" name"test">
   <input class="form-control" name="answers[$i][1]" type="text" placeholder="Answer here"/>
   <button onclick="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button btn btn-success btn-add" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span>
   </button>
   <div class="radio">
      <fieldset id="group1">
         <label>bla bla?</label>&nbsp;
         <label class="radio" ><input name="answers[$i][2]" type="radio" value"1">Ja</label>
         <label class="radio" ><input name="answers[$i][3]" type="radio" value"0">Nein</label>
      </fieldset>
   </div>
</div>
```

Where $i will increase by 1 when new row is added.

Comment: OP is using `twig`, you should reflect that